# Event Delegation, how to target a specific span inside a div

Tags: javascript, event-delegation

Given a bunch of divs like these:

```
<div class="itemGrid">
    <div id="itemOne" class="fruit">
       <span> Banana </span>
          
        </div>

     <div id="itemTwo" class="fruit">
        <span> Apple </span>
          
      </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able, using event delegation, to get the value of the span (so just the text) when I click on those divs.

With this I get everything, the text AND the symbol, but I can't seem to be able to just get the text inside the span:

```
const fruitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".fruit span");
const grid = document.querySelector(".itemGrid");

grid.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName == "DIV") {
    console.log(e.target.textContent)
  }
})
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Reworking the scenario a little:

```js
const fruitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".fruit > span");
const gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".fruit");

// Loop through the div.fruit elements:
gridItems.forEach(function(div){
  
  // Wire each div.fruit to a click handler:
  div.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    // When clicked, look for the first span within the div and get its text
    console.log(div.querySelector("span").textContent);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<div class="itemGrid">
    <div id="itemOne" class="fruit">
       <span> Banana </span>
          
     </div>

     <div id="itemTwo" class="fruit">
        <span> Apple </span>
          
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer was not correct at the time I downvoted; neither it is now because it will fail if I click the main `div`, not the one with `class=fruit`

Comment: Both work just as I wanted, I don't know why are you getting a hard time : ) Thank you.

Comment: @bobjoe You know you can delete your own comments, right?

Comment: this has nothing to do with event delegation

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not a proper `event delegation`

You should check if you clicked inside `div` with `class=fruit`. Then you can extract `text` from its `span` descendant.

```
grid.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let node = e.target;
    let div = null;

    // first let's check if we clicked inside div with class fruit by going up the DOM tree
    while(node !== this){
        if(node.hasClass("fruit")){
            div = node;
            break;
        }

        node = node.parentNode;
    }

    // if we clicked inside, log the value of span
    if(div !== null){
        console.log(div.querySelector("span").textContent);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a solid answer, but `hasClass` is not a valid Javascript function. You should use `node.classList.contains("fruit")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to find the *span* elements under the target.

### Edit:

As was pointed out, one could interpret an *implicit* requirement that the user should be able to click on the *span* elements and have the contents of that element logged. Support for this has been added by adding the *while* loop to search up the chain of ancestors:

```
//search ancestors for div in case user clicks on span element
while (target.nodeName !== "DIV" && e.target.parentNode !== null) {
    target = e.target.parentNode;
}
```

```js
const fruitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".fruit span");
const grid = document.querySelector(".itemGrid");

grid.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  //search ancestors for div in case user clicks on span element
  while (target.nodeName !== "DIV" && e.target.parentNode !== null) {
      target = e.target.parentNode;
  }
  if (target.nodeName == "DIV") {
    var spans = target.getElementsByTagName('span');
    if (spans.length) {
      console.log(spans[0].textContent);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="itemGrid">
  <div id="itemOne" class="fruit">
    <span> Banana </span>
    
  </div>

  <div id="itemTwo" class="fruit">
    <span> Apple </span>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only works if you click on the images. The OP wants to be able to get the text if you click on the `<div>`s.

Comment: The example has been updated to accommodate that requirement.